# Bring a proof for the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f\in \mathscr{R}$ on $[a,b]$ and if there is a differentiable function $F$ on $[a,b]$ such that $F'=f$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ \ d(x)=F(b)-F(a)$$

Comment: You have in the last days posted a couple of self-answered questions. There's nothing wrong with that per se, but for self-answered questions, the same criteria apply as for other questions. Your questions consist merely of the problem statement, which isn't much liked hereabouts. Could you add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) to your questions?

Comment: Right. I felt like there must be something wrong about doing so; and that is improving my questions. Thanks for letting me know @DanielFischer . :)

Answer (score 0):

$f\in \mathscr{R}$, then $\forall \varepsilon$ exists a partition $\mathscr{P}$ on $[a,b]$ such that $U(\mathscr{P},f)-L(\mathscr{P},f)<\varepsilon$.

Since $F$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, from the *mean value theorem*, 
$\forall i=1,\ldots n\ \ \ \ \exists c_i\in [x_{i-1},x_i]; \ \ \ \ F'(c_i)=\dfrac{F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})}{x_i-x_{i-1}}$
$\Longrightarrow F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})=F'(c_i)\ \Delta x_i=f(c_i)\ \Delta x_i$
$\Longrightarrow \sum f(c_i)\ \Delta x_i=\sum F(x_i)-F(x_{i-1})=F(b)-F(a)\ \ \ \ \ \text{(I})$

$f\in \mathscr{R}\Longrightarrow |\sum f(c_i)\ \Delta x_i - \int_a^b f(x)\ dx|<\varepsilon$
$\stackrel{\text{(I)}}{\Longrightarrow} |F(b)-F(a)-\int_a^b f(x)\ dx|<\varepsilon$

Thus,
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=F(b)-F(a)$$

$\square$